# How to return a deeper tree with ASP.NET Core / OOData controller

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

There is an OData controller that provides a singleton resource called `SpareParts`. `SpareParts` has a tree structure. In the `Get` method, that structure is built - for testing purposes with a depth of 10. The full tree is returned by the `Get` method, but in e.g. Postman the result has a reduced depth of only 3.

The controller:

```
public class SparePartController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 0)]
    [Route("odata/spareparts")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        SparePart sparePart = CreateDeepTree();
        return new OkObjectResult(sparePart);
    }

    private SparePart CreateDeepTree()
    {
        return CreateDeepTree(1, 1, "1");
    }

    private SparePart CreateDeepTree(int id, int level, string levelString)
    {
        SparePart sparePart = new SparePart();

        sparePart.Name = "N_" + levelString;
        sparePart.Id = id;

        if (level <= 10) 
            sparePart.Parts.Add(CreateDeepTree(id + 1, level + 1, levelString + "_1"));

        return sparePart;
    }
}
```

The DTO:

```
public class SparePart
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<SparePart> Parts { get; } = new List<SparePart>();
}
```

Program

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new();
        modelBuilder.Singleton<SparePart>("Spareparts");

        NameResolverOptions options = NameResolverOptions.ProcessDataMemberAttributePropertyNames | NameResolverOptions.ProcessReflectedPropertyNames;
        modelBuilder.EnableLowerCamelCase(options);

        builder.Services.AddControllers()
            .AddOData(options =>
            {
                options.EnableQueryFeatures();
                options.AddRouteComponents("odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
            }
        );

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

I'm using .NET 7.0 and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` version 8.2.0.

Url / query:

```
{{Url}}/odata/spareparts?$expand=Parts($expand=Parts($expand=Parts($expand=Parts($expand=Parts))))
```

or

```
{{Url}}/odata/spareparts?$expand=Parts($levels=max)
```

This always returns a with depth lower or equal to 3.

Making the depth to be >= 1 and <=3 works fine. So I guess the OData Infrastructure is working properly.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:7041/odata/$metadata#Spareparts(parts(parts(parts(parts(parts())))))",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "N_1",
    "anotherProperty": "",
    "parts": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "N_1_1",
            "anotherProperty": "",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "N_1_1_1",
                    "anotherProperty": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Question**

How can I get ASP.NET Core / OData to return the tree structure with a depth greater than 3 levels?